# CheckPermissionsAsync always returning Denied on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the [Permissions Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) to request fine location permission on Android; however, every time I call CheckPermissionsAsync, I get a response of Denied.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    PermissionStatus status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse);
    if (status == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
        var result = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse);
    }
}
```

This is running on the emulator and, to my knowledge, I haven't yet managed to execute the `RequestPermissionsAsync` call.

Is this expected behaviour?  If so, how do I differentiate between Denied (not asked yet) and Denied (asked and refused)?

EDIT:

On further investigation, calling `RequestPermissionsAsync` doesn't seem to make any difference either way.  My impression was that it would go to the native platform and display a "We need permissions.." dialogue box.  Looking again at the [samples a bit more for this plug-in](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/blob/master/samples/PermissionsSample/PermissionsSample/Utils.cs), it almost seems like the answer is to just display the settings and let the user allocate whatever they feel; it feels a lot like I'm missing a key part of the puzzle here.

EDIT:

I've created a basic replica of the issue [here](https://github.com/pcmichaels/XamarinPermissionIssue/tree/master/XamarinPermissionsIssue) (obviously I've removed the Google Maps key).

EDIT:

Following @FreakyAli's advice, I ended up with a Main Activity that looks like this (more or less):

```
if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
        Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation))
{

}
else
{                    
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this,
            new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation },
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);    
}
```

This works, but it feels like I'm replicating what the plug-in does.

Comment: have you declared the permission in the manifest?

Comment: AFAIK, I am not sure if you can differentiate in between them without writing your own logic for this, by default XF or native does not have anything as such

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes - I've declared ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in the manifest

Comment: Check the permission of your app in system setting page .

Comment: @PaulMichaels I went this road and to differentiate that you need to save a flag (say via preferences) after the first request. We cannot rely on `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync()` method.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "system setting page"

Comment: Are you on `Xamarin.Forms` Android or `Xamarin.Android`?

Comment: Xamarin Forms - sorry - I've updated the tags

Comment: Can you give me a gist of what is the issue, because after reading your question and the comments I am still a bit confused

Comment: The gist is that I'm trying to use Google Maps, but when I launch the screen that hosts it, I get an error from Android telling me that it needs permission to use the location, and I don't seem to be able to get Android to ask for, or grant that permission

Comment: Oh now I understand give me a min or so @PaulMichaels is this what you want https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/4p/7rnfetfzewzm.png ?

Comment: Yes, a dialogue box that just requests location

Comment: So do you just want this for Android or Both?

Comment: The question only relates to Android.  However, I will need to solve the same issue for iOS at some stage, but as I understand the Permissions Plug-in, it essentially works cross platform.  I don't want to write a lot of Android specific code to make this work for Android if that can be avoided.

Comment: You will have to write an Android-specific dependency service for this one actually

Comment: @FreakyAli I've updated the question - I ended up going you the approach of manually coding the Android activity.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have added the following code in Activity OnCreate Method:

```
 Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

1. add location permission to the manifest file.

2.check permission status, and request permission.

```
  private async void Btn1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
        try
        {
             status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");

                }

                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                status = results[Permission.Location];
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
               //do something about location.
            }
            else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

3. override OnRequestPermissionsResult method.

   ```
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] 
       permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
   {
       base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
   }
   ```

4.Set the following in your Activity's OnCreate method.

```
 Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, this is essentially what the readme for the plug-in says, so I've already done all of this.

Comment: @Paul, I have upload the Mainactivity and activity_main.xaml in github, please take a look:https://github.com/CherryBu/Permission

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've checked your repo, and I can't see anything in it that I'm not already doing.

Comment: @PaulMichaels, Can you provide one demo that can reproduce this issue in github, I will download your sample to test at my side.

Comment: See the latest edit - I've created a public repo that replicates the issue that I'm having.

Comment: @Paul,I download you sample from [github](https://github.com/pcmichaels/XamarinPermissionIssue), but I don't see where you check and request permission?

Comment: The check is in App.xaml.cs

Comment: @Paul, I find you don't select ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in Android Manifest, please select ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, then add `Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` in Activity's OnCreate method, it is very important

Comment: @Paul,I also suggest you to request location permission when you need, for example, you want to get latitude Longitude,you can request location permission, don't recommend use these code in app.cs at the beginning.

Comment: Why do I need Coarse Location?  I was under the impression that you requested course OR fine location, not both.

Comment: The app that I'm writing is, essentially, a location app.  I wanted to ask right at the start whether I could have permission.  I assume this doesn't stop the location permission working?

Comment: @Paul, Please make sure you have added the `Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` in your MainActivity OnCreate method.

Comment: @Paul, I refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows) about coarse and fine location, but you also don't need to select coarse, I test it when I don't select coarse location, it works fine.

Comment: I had added the CrossCurrentActivity in the main project.  It makes no difference to the behaviour (I've pushed the changed code to the repo).  I've also tried with coarse location, but that also makes no difference.

Comment: @Paul, I try your code,yes, it doesn't request location location, I suggest you can move your request permission code in MianPage.cs OnAppearing method, it can works fine and can get location permission when app load.